# Sort matrix colnames to match element order in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a particular list such as:

```
my_list<-list("Cluster18904", "Cluster6294", "Cluster17424", "Cluster26257", 
     "Cluster27053", "Cluster2905", "Cluster16096", "Cluster14552")
```

which looks like:

> `my_list`

```
[[1]]
[1] "Cluster18904"

[[2]]
[1] "Cluster6294"

[[3]]
[1] "Cluster17424"

[[4]]
[1] "Cluster26257"

[[5]]
[1] "Cluster27053"

[[6]]
[1] "Cluster2905"

[[7]]
[1] "Cluster16096"

[[8]]
[1] "Cluster14552"
```

and I have a matrix with the same colnames but I'm looking for a solution in order to order the column of the matrix to match the same order as in `my_list`

I tried:

```
as.data.frame(matrix)[,my_list]
```

But I get :

> Error in .subset(x, j) : 'list' incorrect index type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to `unlist`

```
as.data.frame(matrix)[, unlist(my_list)]
```

---

if there are column names not matching, then use `intersect`

```
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix)
nm1 <- intersect(names(dat1), unlist(my_list))
dat1[nm1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will sort the column names according to the list names, by first converting the list names to a vector of strings.

```
matrix[,match(colnames(matrix),as.character(my_list))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
as.data.frame(matrix)[simplify2array(my_list)]
```